# How to Learn how a library works

Tags: java, json

This is kind of an abstract question.

In general, how do I go about learning a library? I don't mean learning how to use it, I mean learning the design and the details of the interworkings.

For some more detail about what I mean, here is the situation that prompted me to ask this question.

My service has the ability to record a call's dependent data into a json blob. I'm working on some code that reads in the json blob, reconstructs the objects in the blob, and replays the call from the blob. The issue that I'm running into is that when one of the objects is being reconstructed I'm getting an exception that says "Field X cannot be null," but the field is not null in the json blob so obviously something is wrong. The stack trace is about 15 levels deep inside the Jackson library, so it's not easy to tell what's going wrong.

I honestly don't mind learning how the library works to fix this problem. I think it will be interesting. I just don't know where to start. I feel like I was just handed a big project full of files with no direction other than that, at a high level, I can imagine how serializing and deserializing Java objects would work.

Comment: Read the source code? Start from the API level that you know how to call and work your way into the details. Also as a btw, an IDE with "jump to definition", "find usages" and similar features helps a lot when tracing through code.

Comment: This right here what @MattiVirkkunen just said. Programming is 80% about reading code.

Comment: Start with the interfaces, and then dive in.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, how do I go about learning a library? I don't mean
>   learning how to use it, I mean learning the design and the details of
>   the interworkings.

Generally, mature libraries (like `Jackson` as you mentioned in your question) have good introductions in their documentation as to their design.  You can then drill down deeper for "the details of the interworkings" going as far as source code if needed.

I think a good general order in learning a library is the following
1. Introductory/high level/design view
2. More specific sections
3. Source code (rarely should have to go to this level)

I generally don't find myself as low as the source code view when learning a library...after all, if you're down at that level, one could argue you could write the code yourself...libraries are there to abstract away all the code needed to accomplish a task (like JSON data-binding in the case of `Jackson`).

I like how the [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/%20jackson-databind) page lays things out nicely in a general-specific order...you can get up and running right away and drill deeper if needed further down the page.

Give yourself time to learn a library...it doesn't happen overnight...

Answer (score 1):

> In general, how do I go about learning a library? I don't mean learning how to use it, I mean learning the design and the details of the interworkings.

In general, you don't.  That's the point.  A well-written library has a stable and well-documented interface.  When it comes to Java libraries, "well-documented" means exactly one thing: [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).  You can browse the Javadoc to get an overview of the library, and you can attach the Javadoc to your project in your IDE so you can view the documentation for a class or method just by hovering your mouse pointer over it.  The library's clients (the programs that use it) and the programmer writing them should not know or care how it works internally.  If you know how it works, you may come to depend on how it works, and then your programs will break when it changes.

If you want to make sure a library isn't doing something stupid or malicious, or you want to study it for educational purposes, the best thing to do is read the source.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is reading the Library's source code not just reading reference file.I suggest you use Java Decompiler or Jad tools to get source code.